# How can we replicate dependency registration from StructureMap in Microsoft DI

Tags: dependency-injection

With structuremap we can register interfaces like this:

```
Scan(x =>
            {
                x.AssemblyContainingType<Startup>();
                x.Assembly("Api");
                x.LookForRegistries();
                x.AddAllTypesOf<Profile>();
                x.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
```

If I have Interface and multiple concrete implementations use that interface, IService, ServiceA, ServiceB, ServiceC, how can I do that with Microsoft DI, or do I have to write down addtransient 3 times?

Same for strategy pattern:

```
public class ServiceStrategy : IServiceStrategy
{
    private readonly List<IService> _services;

    public ServiceStrategy(List<IService> services)
    {
        this._services= services;
    }

    public string GetProcedure(Enum enum, EnumTwo enum2)
    {
        return this._managers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == enum)
            ?.GetProcedure(enum2);
    }
}
```

How can I register strategy here?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection lacks any Auto-Registration abilities, so you have 3 options:

- Register each component explicitly, by having one call to `AddTransient` per component
- Write the Auto-Registration yourself by reflecting over assemblies, filtering out the right types and register them. Depending on your requirements this can vary in complexity.
- Switch to a more mature, feature right DI Container.